# Нужна ли запятая перед "удостоверившись"?

Tags: пунктуация

Мой ядовитый ответ не производит впечатления: докторша невозмутимо измеряет мне давление и, удостоверившись, что все в норме, предлагает отправиться домой.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна.

*Удостоверившись, что все в норме* - деепричастный оборот внутри предложения. Он обособляется запятыми с двух сторон.

Основа предложения - *докторша измеряет* (кому, что) *и* (деепричастный оборот) *предлагает*.